# Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R$ (reals) infinity? if so, can somebody tell me the Lebesgue measure of $[0,1] \cup \mathbb Q$ (rationals)? Just a curiosity question.

Comment: May I ask why you're interested in these two sets in particular? And what is the connection between them?

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}$ it is infinity. For $\mathbb{Q}$ it is zero. For $[0,1]$ it is $1$.

Comment: I'm just curios. Because we had shown in class that the measure of rationals is 0, and the measure of [0 1] intersected with the irrationals is 1.    Yes but the Q united with [0,1]? Because [0,1] and Q are not disjuncted sets

Comment: Sure, but if $\mathbb Q$ has measure $0$, then $[0,1]^c \cap \mathbb Q$, being a subset of $\mathbb Q$, also has measure $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Countable additivity and translation invariance answer both questions if you know that the measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$ and the measure of a set containing just one point is $0.$ The measure of every set of the form $[a,a+1]$ must be the same as the measure of $[0,1]$ by translation invariance. The whole line contains the union of a countably infinite collection of such sets that are pairwise disjoint; for example $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\text{even } n} [n,n+1].$ Hence the measure of the real line is $\ge1+1+1+\cdots = \infty$ and is therefore $\infty.$

The set of all rational numbers is countable, so its measure is the sum of the measures of sets each containing just one rational number. That means it is $0+0+0+\cdots = 0.$

Therefore the measure of $[0,1]\cup\mathbb Q$ is $1.$

Comment: Ok but, [0,1] and Q are not disjoints sets? Does that mean we can write Q as Q\[0 1] ? and the [0,1] U (Q\[0 1])? and the 1-0=1?

Comment: @valer : The measure of $A\cup B$ is $\le$ the sum of the measures of $A$ and $B$, and the measure of $A\cup B$ is _equal to_ the sum of the measures if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. So we can say that the measure of the union of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb Q$ is less-than-or-equal-to the sum of their measures. The sum of their measures is $1.$ So the measure of the union is not more than $1.$ But it also cannot be less than $1$ because $[0,1]$ is a subset that has measure $1. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets then so are $A\cup B, B\cap A, A$ \ $B,$ and $B$ \ $A.$ Therefore $$m(A)\leq m(A)+m(B \backslash A)\leq m(A)+[m(B \backslash  
A)+m(B\cap A)]=m(A)+m(B).$$ Since $m(A)+m(B$ \ $A)=m(A \cup (B$ \ $A))=m(A\cup B)$ we have $$ m(A)\leq m(A\cup B)\leq m(A)+m(B).$$ In particular if $m(B)=0$ then  $m(A)=m(A\cup B).$